# Forcar a subclasse

Tags: c#

como faco para forcar a subclasse exibir os dados corretos?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tran = new List<Transporte>();
        tran.Add(new Navio());   // Objetos das subclasses   
        tran.Add(new Aviao());   // podem pertencer   
        tran.Add(new Onibus());  // ao tipo da Superclasse.   
        Console.WriteLine(" exemplo aplicação polimorfismo .");
        for (int i = 0; i < tran.Count; i++)
        {
            tran[i].exibeDados();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Transporte
{
    public void exibeDados()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("classe transporte: Método para exibição dos dados.");
    }
}

public class Aviao : Transporte
{
    // Sobreposição do método da superclasse
    public void exibeDados()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Aviao");
    }
}

public class Navio : Transporte
{
    // Sobreposição do método da superclasse
    public void exibeDados()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Navio");
    }
}

public class Onibus : Transporte
{
    public void exibeDados()
    {
        // Sobreposição do método da superclasse
        Console.WriteLine("Onibus");
    }
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao SO PT. Adicione mais detalhes sobre seu problema, pois não esta claro qual problema esta encontrando e qual o resultado esperado.

Answer (score 1):

Adicionando o modificador [`virtual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) no método da classe base e depois fazendo o `override` na classe derivada:

```
public class Transporte
{
    public virtual void exibeDados()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("classe transporte: Método para exibição dos dados.");
    }
}

public class Aviao : Transporte
{
    // Sobreposição do método da superclasse
    public override void exibeDados()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Aviao");
    }
}
```

Desta forma, indicada que as classes derivadas que não façam `override` do método, imprimam "classe transporte...".

Caso faca `override` (como e o caso da classe Aviao), quando invocar o método `exibeDados()`, vai executar o que estiver no metodo da classe derivada (neste caso imprime "Aviao").

Comment: Apesar da brevidade da questão, julgo que a palavra chave aqui seja *forçar*. Tornar o método `virtual` não *força* as subclasses a re-definir o método .

Comment: @dcastro mas o OP também não indica que deseja forcar as classes a redefinir o método, só diz que quer forcar as classes derivadas a apresentar a mensagem. O que para ser sincero, indica que o problema esta na pergunta do OP, dado que a meu ver ambas as respostas (e por isso e que votei +1 na sua) estao correctas.

Comment: Concordo, a pergunta está aberta a interpretações e devia ser mais específica.

Answer (score 1):

Para *forçar* a subclasse a implementar o método `ExibeDados`, o método deve ser abstracto (marcado com a keyword `abstract`). Consequentemente, a classe `Transporte` também deverá ser abstracta e, como tal, nunca poderá ser instanciada directamente (o que me parece ser o desejado, nesta situacao).

```
public abstract class Transporte
{
    public abstract void ExibeDados();
}

public class Aviao : Transporte
{
    public override void ExibeDados()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Aviao");
    }
}
```

Parece-me que tornar a classe abstracta seja o mais indicado nesta situação - o exemplo do Transporte VS Avião/Navio, e o exemplo da Forma Geométrica VS Quadrado/Triângulo são muito usados para demonstrar situações em que a classe base deve ser abstracta.

Se o caso real for diferente do da pergunta, e se a classe não puder ser abstracta, então a resposta é: não é possível. Uma classe não abstracta não pode forçar classes derivadas.

Nota: [a convenção dita que o nome dos métodos se escrevam em PascalCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx), então o método deve chamar-se `ExibeDados` em vez de `exibeDados`.